How to create a dynamic dimension in Power BI
How can I create a dimension in Power BI that changes relative to selected condition. In this very case if a share of SKU is less then 10% out of total it gets a new name "other". I belive this can be done in Qlik with aggr to return an array of values from a virtual table. Does Power BI allow such a thing?


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So using DAX, I created a calculated table based on your original one:
AggregatedTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'SKU',
    'SKU'[SKU],
    "Value", SUM('SKU'[VALUE])
)

and added a calculated column for the overall sum :
TotalValue = SUMX(AggregatedTable, [Value])


Then % Share as a calculated column:
Share = DIVIDE(AggregatedTable[Value], [TotalValue], 0)


Then a flag column for rows having the value < 10% :
Flag = IF(AggregatedTable[Share] < 0.1, 1 , 0)

To help me create the New SKU :
New SKU = IF(AggregatedTable[Flag]=1, "Other", CONVERT(AggregatedTable[SKU], STRING))


Finally in your visual you choose the New SKU column and the Share with SUM as aggregation :

